# How do I Open Firefox in a normal way(with out "The address isn't valid" screen) using selenium web-driver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, browser, webdriver

I am trying to go to a website using selenium web-driver and python for Firefox, but every time It opens Firefox I first see the "The address isn't valid " screen which makes me mad. Could you please help me out on how to fix this and open Firefox without the screen.[Here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWCuq.png)

Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that someone can help diagnose your problem.

Comment: What difference does it make? You aren't testing that page and plan to navigate to a different site anyway.

Comment: See the link: https://www.chrismorbitzer.com/2016/08/26/selenium-firefox-webdriver-fails-to-load/

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
from selenium import webdriver


class WebBrowser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def open_site(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)


browser = WebBrowser()
browser.open_site("")
```

This works for me . I just send a empty string . If it still fails you can always `.sendkeys()` for going home.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i'll try this out.

Comment: No problem. If you want firefox to do something 'crazy' create a profile and have firefox load it up before launching.